# timedelta - most elegant way to pass 'days=-5' from string

Tags: python

I am trying call a function that triggers a report to be generated with a starting date that is either hour or days ago.  The code below works fine but I would like to store the timedelta offset in a mysql database.

```
starting_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=-5)
```

I had hoped to store  'days=-5' in the database, extract that database column to variable 'delta_offset' and then run

```
starting_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(delta_offset)
```

It doesnt like this because delta_offset is a string. I know i could modify the function to just include the offset and store -5 in my database, like what is below.  But I really wanted to store days=-5 in the database because my offset can be hours as well.  I could make my offset in database always hours and store -120 in the database but was wondering if there was an elegant way where I store 'days=-5' in the database and not cause type issues

```
starting_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=delta_offset)
```

Comment: You should probably store the number of seconds in the database (or whatever the smallest unit your offset can be), and then use that to build the `timedelta`.

Comment: Do you realize that you're subtracting a negative offset, thus you're actually getting a _later_ time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing `'days=-5'` in your database as a single column, you could break this into two columns named 'value' and 'unit' or similar.
Then you can pass these to timedelta in a dictionary and unpacking. Like so:

```
unit = 'days'
value = -5
starting_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(**{unit: value})
```

This will unpack the dictionary so you get the same result as doing `timedelta([unit]=value)`.

Alternatively, if you really would like to keep `'days=-5'` as a value of a single column in your database, you could split the string on `'='` then take a similar approach. Here's how:

```
offset = 'days=-5'
unit, value = offset.split('=')
starting_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(**{unit: int(value)})
```

Comment: this is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i would do it this way:

```
    date_offset_split = date_offset.split("=")
    kwargs = {date_offset_split[0]: int(date_offset_split[1])}

    starting_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(**kwargs)
```